# Firebase Messaging Inactivity, disconnecting from AppMeasurementService

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Im trying to send notifications into an Android Emulator device using FCM Messages but I dont get no one notification.
google app id is the same that inside google-services.json

this is what I get from console:

D/FA: Connected to remote service

V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1

V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from AppMeasurementService

my build.gradle (Module:app):

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.cris.firebasenotificationexam"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 23
```

....

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2'
}
```

Anyone knows how to fix this problem?

Comment: Hard to determine what's causing this with the details you provided. Can you post your `onMessageReceived()` implementation and a sample payload?

Answer (score 0):

The log message: *Inactivity, disconnecting from AppMeasurementService*, is normal and not an indication if a problem.

Edit the dependencies block of your `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2'
}

// Moved the following statement.  Was in the dependencies block
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

More details in the [Firebase Setup Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add_the_sdk).

Also, consider using the latest released versions of the libraries: 9.8.0 for firebase-messaging and 25.0.1 for appcompat-v7.